# makefile function call not working as expected

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm having an issue with two functions that I have defined and they are as follows:

```
#return the full path of the passed in dir/file with the drive letter removed
define clean_path
$(patsubst $(DRIVE_ROOT)/%,/%,$(abspath $(1)))
endef

#appends the root directory name to the paths except for paths that are absolute.
define qualify_path
$(addprefix $(1),$(filter-out /%,$(2))) $(filter /%,$(2))
endef
```

The qualify_path function is to look at a list of paths and any directory that doesnt start with / it will add $(1) to it. Both of these functions work independently but my problem is when I am using them together.

In a makefile I have the following lines:

```
TEMP_DIRS := $(call qualify_path, $(lastword $(dirstack)), $(SRC_INCDIRS))
$(info TEMP_DIRS = $(TEMP_DIRS))
CLEAN_DIRS := $(call clean_path, $(TEMP_DIRS))
$(info CLEAN_DIRS = $(CLEAN_DIRS))
```

When these lines get run I end up with $(TEMP_DIRS) having the appropriate values assigned to it but $(CLEAN_DIRS) has the same values as $(TEMP_DIRS). I have $(TEMP_DIRS) just for debugging at this point I would really just want to combine them like this:

```
CLEAN_DIRS := $(call clean_path, $(call qualify_path, $(lastword $(dirstack)), $(SRC_INCDIRS)))
```

Now if I use this instead of doing a call to clean_path:

```
TEMP_DIRS := $(call qualify_path, $(lastword $(dirstack)), $(SRC_INCDIRS))
$(info TEMP_DIRS = $(TEMP_DIRS))
CLEAN_DIRS := $(patsubst $(DRIVE_ROOT)/%,/%,$(abspath $(TEMP_DIRS)))
$(info CLEAN_DIRS = $(CLEAN_DIRS))
```

$(CLEAN_DIRS) has all the right values in it. I am sure it has something to do with expansion orders, using eval, or something of the sort but I really cannot figure this out. If someone could please explain the proper way of doing what I am attempting that would be great. As always thanks for your time.

Comment: I were unable to reproduce it. Could you post the input values for `DRIVE_ROOT`, `dirstack`, etc? Or even better, the whole makefile?

Comment: Let me try to reproduce it in a simple makefile for you, thanks for trying

Comment: Now of course when I am recreating this in a simpler test case everything works correctly, anybody got any shots in the dark to try? i am combing over the differences now

Comment: well, I would only recommend you to check whitespaces, because GNU Make is very sensitive to them.

Comment: any particular region for white spaces? I have whitespace set to visible in vim so I can see tabs vs. spaces. As you can see the function definitions are just 1 line so I don't think there any spacing issue that can go wrong there. Are there spacing requirements for the $(call) $(patsubst) etc. functions? I wasn't aware of any

Comment: Binary search. Try a makefile halfway between the two. Keep splitting until you find *one change* that makes the difference.

Comment: @Beta good to hear from you man, been really absorbing your make prowess on here. That's what I was going to do is to comment out everything in the non working one until it starts working and then start adding stuff back in. I will definitely post back up the results when I figure it out

Comment: Thanks, but don't give me too much credit; there are a lot of Make experts here, like Eldar Abusalimov and [my nemesis](http://stackoverflow.com/users/429232/jack-kelly), from whom I've learned a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this one was of course a stupid mistake and there would've been no chance to finding it for anyone else. I had previously defined the clean_path function in a separate makefile that I was including that were system commands for a unix system or windows system since I don't need to clean the path for a unix system it was blank. I guess having the function defined in two different places was messing up make so it just did nothing. I found the problem commenting everything out until it worked and then adding stuff back in piece by piece. Once I uncommented out the windows command include it broke again so I looked in there and there was the clean_path function. Thanks for the help and time guys.